# Android development bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was wondering is it possible to connect a bluetooth device to send and receive signals from my to PC to an external device i.e. mobile phone through the android simulator?

Comment: While it's not possible via the emulator, you can easily get a bluetooth adapter for your computer (if you don't already have bluetooth) and do this with bluez. PyBluez makes it very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at present.

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/projects/bluetooth-faq